# Unit testing AngularJS $http event handler with Jasmine/Karma?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, http, karma-jasmine, eventhandler

I'm using AngularJS 1.5.8, and I have a factory with a method that returns an instance of an $http request. It includes a progress `eventHandler`. My question is, how can I test this event handler using Jasmine/Karma? Normally, requests are tested by mocking them up via `$httpBackend.expectPOST` or similar, but then the progress event is never fired. And if I don't mock it up, Karma complains about an unexpected request. How do I do this?

Comment: can you share some relevant code?

Comment: Unfortunately not, as it's proprietary code. But the basic form is just using AngularJS's $http to create a request, and setting its eventHandlers object to have a progress function to call back when progress is received. I need to make sure that callback is being called, but I have no idea how to mock up a progress event on $http in a unit test.

Comment: I'm not sure what event handlers are you talking about, $http returns u the http response whenever it ready.

Comment: $http returns a promise for an AJAX call. You can pass it an object as its parameter that determines things like the URL, the request method, etc. One of those options is eventHandlers, which you can use to attach callbacks on certain events, such as response progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The way to do this is to use AngularJS decorators to extend the $httpBackend, thus being able to intercept calls to the backend, log the handlers passed to them, and delegate out to the original object:

```
    var httpDecorator = function($delegate) {
    $delegate.eventHandlers = [];
    var newBackend = function() {
      $delegate.eventHandlers.push(arguments[8]);
      return $delegate.apply(null, arguments);
    };
    angular.forEach($delegate, function(value, key) {
      if ($delegate.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        newBackend[key] = value;
      }
    });
    return newBackend;
  };
  $provide.decorator('$httpBackend', ['$delegate', httpDecorator]);
```

With that set up in the `module(...)` definition in a `beforeEach(...)` callback, now I can reference `$httpBackend.eventHandlers` in my unit tests and get references to all of them :)